# Fleek hosting on Internet Computer build failing exceeded the cycles limit for single message execution

Tags: reactjs, build, hosting, ipfs, internet-computer

I've been trying to host my Github Repo over Fleek, I'm new to Fleek (Decentralised Hosting). I can't see any error creating issues during or before build completion.

This is the Deploy log of build that I am trying to host.

```
6:39:30 PM 03/15/2022: Deploy started
6:39:32 PM 03/15/2022: Docker image: 'fleek/create-react-app:node-16'
6:39:32 PM 03/15/2022: Build command: 'yarn && yarn build'
6:39:32 PM 03/15/2022: Triggering build execution...
6:40:23 PM 03/15/2022: yarn install v1.22.5
6:40:23 PM 03/15/2022: warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
6:40:23 PM 03/15/2022: [1/4] Resolving packages...
6:40:24 PM 03/15/2022: [2/4] Fetching packages...
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning " > @testing-library/user-event@13.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning "@walletconnect/web3-provider > web3-provider-engine > eth-block-tracker > @babel/plugin-transform-runtime > babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2 > @babel/helper-define-polyfill-provider@0.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.4.0-0".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning " > react-dom@17.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@17.0.2".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning " > react-grid-carousel@1.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^16.12.0".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning " > react-native-svg@12.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@>=0.50.0".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning "recharts > react-smooth@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.0".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning " > slick-carousel@1.8.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=1.8.0".
6:40:47 PM 03/15/2022: warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
6:41:13 PM 03/15/2022: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
6:41:21 PM 03/15/2022: Done in 58.15s.
6:41:21 PM 03/15/2022: yarn run v1.22.5
6:41:21 PM 03/15/2022: $ react-scripts build
6:41:23 PM 03/15/2022: Creating an optimized production build...
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Compiled with warnings.
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: ./node_modules/magic-sdk/dist/es/index.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: ./node_modules/magic-sdk/dist/es/index.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/App.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 5:50: 'Navigate' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 11:8: 'OwnerScam' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 18:8: 'Safecards' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 19:8: 'SafeOwners' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 20:8: 'OngoingScam' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 47:11: 'fetchBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/Web3_connection/ContractMethods.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 6:10: 'getWeb3' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/Web3_connection/web3_methods.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 44:11: 'connectorId' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Bottomnav.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 25:11: 'fetchBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/BuyBBT.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 23:29: <iframe> elements must have a unique title property jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Contact.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 34:36: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 49:39: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Devdetails.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 13:9: 'location' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 15:9: 'notify' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 51:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Devprofile.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 60:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/InfluencerDetails.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 2:10: 'ToastContainer' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 5:10: 'addReview' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 6:10: 'Link' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 13:9: 'location' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 15:9: 'notify' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 52:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/InfluencerProfile.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 59:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Ownerdetails.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 11:10: 'getTotoalProfile' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 12:10: 'initInstance' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 19:9: 'location' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 92:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchedOwner'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Ownerprofile.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 22:12: 'tokenBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 22:22: 'setTokenBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 62:8: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/PageBoobyTrap.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 2:16: 'Outlet' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/PlatformHead.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 3:10: 'Outlet' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 4:10: 'ABI' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 16:8: 'SidebarSlide' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 22:10: 'Interface' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 28:7: 'provider' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 31:5: 'result' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 50:13: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside:
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: useEffect(() => {
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: async function fetchData() {
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: // You can await here
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: // ...
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: }
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: fetchData();
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: }, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Learn more about data fetching with Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/hooks-data-fetching react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 59:33: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 86:9: 'authButton' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 87:9: 'resultBox' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 183:18: 'testCall' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Projectdetails.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 10:19: 'id' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 64:15: Effect callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions. Put the async function inside:
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: useEffect(() => {
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: async function fetchData() {
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: // You can await here
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: // ...
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: }
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: fetchData();
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: }, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Learn more about data fetching with Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/hooks-data-fetching react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 95:81: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 96:69: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 97:71: Expected '===' and instead saw '==' eqeqeq
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Projectpage.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 6:22: 'BsStarHalf' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 8:10: 'ToastContainer' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 14:10: 'getAccount' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 22:10: 'tokenBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 22:20: 'setTokenBal' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 87:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 92:10: 'name' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/PromoterDetails.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 7:10: 'start' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 14:9: 'location' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 16:9: 'notify' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 61:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/PromoterProfile.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 68:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/SafeHaven.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 2:10: 'Outlet' is defined but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: src/component/Safecards.js
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Line 16:10: 'CountProfile' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
6:43:46 PM 03/15/2022: File sizes after gzip:
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 1.31 MB build/static/js/6.bb57bdc6.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 72.92 KB build/static/js/2.31657dde.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 63.4 KB build/static/js/0.fb87e029.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 44.24 KB build/static/js/main.a7ac5c37.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 40.33 KB build/static/js/3.ed5f1e75.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 34.84 KB build/static/js/7.e0ac4c51.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 31.87 KB build/static/css/6.d08911bb.chunk.css
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 11.17 KB build/static/js/12.781c04f1.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 10.46 KB build/static/js/1.4d422217.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 5.91 KB build/static/css/main.f87460db.chunk.css
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 2.48 KB build/static/js/11.e85a8679.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 2.39 KB build/static/js/16.34ceeb47.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 2.1 KB build/static/js/8.a7050cf8.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 1.73 KB build/static/js/17.57a74ea9.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 1.53 KB build/static/js/15.3094f41e.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 1.31 KB build/static/js/runtime-main.d0607358.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 446 B build/static/js/14.8ab9dbfe.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 158 B build/static/js/10.b9f52d05.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 158 B build/static/js/9.4faebcd2.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 153 B build/static/js/13.678ede53.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: 138 B build/static/js/18.c57bc1e4.chunk.js
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: Consider reducing it with code splitting 
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: You can also analyze the project dependencies
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: The build folder is ready to be deployed.
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: You may serve it with a static server:
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: yarn global add serve
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: serve -s build
6:43:47 PM 03/15/2022: Done in 145.51s.
6:43:48 PM 03/15/2022: Setting wallet for identity 'default' on network 'ic' to id 'owdog-wiaaa-aaaad-qaaaq-cai'
6:43:48 PM 03/15/2022: Wallet set successfully.
6:43:48 PM 03/15/2022: Deploying all canisters.
6:43:48 PM 03/15/2022: Creating canisters...
6:43:48 PM 03/15/2022: Creating canister "hosting"...
6:44:43 PM 03/15/2022: The Replica returned an error: code 5, message: "Canister owdog-wiaaa-aaaad-qaaaq-cai exceeded the cycles limit for single message execution."
6:45:07 PM 03/15/2022: Error occured during the upload.
```

I couldn't get the main issue of this error why does it fails after build?

Any solution will be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error, not promising so I use IPFS as backend end it works fine.